# Understanding service --status-all output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sendmail, service

I am trying to understand the output of the `service --status-all` command on Ubuntu 13.10, since the man page doesn't explain it. For example:

```
[ + ]  rsyslog
[ - ]  sendmail
[ ? ]  sendsigs
[ + ]  setvtrgb
[ - ]  ssh
```

What do `+`, `-`, `?` mean? I can't figure it out. I had sendmail installed before but I stopped and removed it with `apt-get remove sendmail*`. I guess that didn't get rid of the init script in `/etc/init.d/` and that's why it shows it in the output, but at least it's a `-`, so I assume it's not running. Then, SSH. I'm actually SSH-ing into the server, so I assume the SSH service should be running, but it's a `-` there anyway. And then there's the cryptic `?`. Somebody please shed some light on what this actually means.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `service --status-all` command tries to figure out for every init script in `/etc/init.d` if it supports a `status` command (by grepping the script for `status`).

If it doesn't find that string it will print `[ ? ]` for that service.

Otherwise it will run `/etc/init.d/$application status`.
If the return code is 0 it prints `[ + ]`.
If it's not 0 it prints `[ - ]`.

Why does `ssh` print `[ - ]` even though it's still running?
`ssh` is controlled by upstart in Ubuntu (13.10).
Running `/etc/init.d/ssh status` will produce no output and a return code of 1.

Comment: Oh, upstart. Thanks for the detailed reply, `service --status-all` is much more clear to me now. So to get a full picture I should also use `initctl list` and kind of "or" the results together? Is there some more complete and comprehensive way?

Comment: Yep use also `initctl list` or just general `ps ...`, at least until `systemd` is being used...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `systemd`, now I'm looking forward to 14.10...

Comment: As far as I know 14.10 doesn't use `systemd` yet, but I'm not a Ubuntu guy. I could be wrong.

Comment: 14.10 isn't out yet, they're planning to offer it as an alternative to `upstart` but both will work in the near future apparently

Comment: Note that the output of `service --service-all` does **not** seem to guarantee to be the same as `service [service] status` (it *should*, usually, most of the time). see https://askubuntu.com/questions/860353/service-command-why-service-status-all-and-service-servicename-status-return ford etails